# Can I factorize $\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1 +\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2$ into $ \sin(\theta_1 +\theta_2)\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$?

Tags: trigonometry, factoring

I was studying Fresnel coefficients, and to get the proper answer, I need to know how to factorize $$\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1 +\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2$$ into $$ \sin(\theta_1 +\theta_2)\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$ but I can't find an easy way to do so. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why not just expand the expression and see if it is the correct factorization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$T = \sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1 +\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2 = \frac{\sin(2\theta_1)+\sin(2\theta_2)}{2}.$$
Let $x = \theta_1+\theta_2$ and $y = \theta_1-\theta_2$. Then
$$T = \frac{\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)}{2}=\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(y)}{2}=\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2).$$

Answer (score 1):

The following formulae are usually proved in an elementary trig class:
\begin{align*}
\sin(\alpha\pm\beta)&=\sin\alpha\cos\beta\pm\sin\beta\cos\alpha\\
\cos(\alpha\pm\beta)&=\cos\alpha\cos\beta\mp\sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
\end{align*}
Thus, applying these to your problem gives
\begin{align*}
\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)&=(\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1)(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)\\
&=\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1\cos^2\theta_2+\sin^2\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2\\
&\quad+\cos^2\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2+\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_1\sin^2\theta_2\\
&=\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_1+\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_2
\end{align*}
after using $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$.